# El programa sigue de largo cuando pido un string por teclado en JAVA

Tags: java, string, java-util-scanner

como estan?

Hace muy poco estoy aprendiendo a programar usando JAVA como lenguaje, y estoy teniendo un inconveniente dentro de un while, que a su vez esta dentro de un for.

El while ingresa cuando el string **libro** es diferente a "FIN". La variable la inicializo pidiendo el dato por teclado antes de entrar al while.

Una vez que entra, lo que hago al final de ese while es pedir el ingreso por teclado de la variable **libro**, y el programa sigue de largo sin permitirme ingresar datos.

No puedo encontrar donde esta el error. Agradecería mucho su ayuda. Mil gracias!

Este seria el codigo:

```
private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int cantLibros = 0, cantHojas, maxHojas, generoI = 0, generoN = 0, generoH = 0, promedioLibros;

    final int ESTANTERIAS = 5;

    char genero;

    String maxLibro, libro;

    for (int i = 1; i <= ESTANTERIAS; i++) {

        maxHojas = 0;
        maxLibro = "";

        System.out.println("Libros en estanteria nro: " + i);

        System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del libro (escriba FIN para finalizar la carga): ");

        libro = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();

        while (!libro.equals("FIN")) {

            cantLibros++;

            do {
                System.out.println("Indique cuantas hojas tiene el libro: ");
                cantHojas = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());

            } while (cantHojas < 1);

            if (cantHojas > maxHojas) {

                maxHojas = cantHojas;
                maxLibro = libro;
            }

            do {
                System.out.println("Ingrese genero ('I': Infantil, 'N': Novela, 'H': Historia): ");
                genero = input.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);

            } while (genero != 'I' && genero != 'N' && genero != 'H');

            switch (genero) {

            case 'I':
                generoI++;
                break;

            case 'H':
                generoH++;
                break;

            case 'N':
                generoN++;
                break;
            }


            System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del libro (escriba FIN para finalizar la carga): ");

            libro = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();

        }

        System.out.println(
                "El libro con mayor cantidad de hojas es: " + maxLibro + " y contiene: " + maxHojas + " hoja/s");
    }

    promedioLibros = cantLibros / ESTANTERIAS;

    System.out.println("La cantidad de libros del genero infantil es: " + generoI + " libro/s");
    System.out.println("La cantidad de libros del genero historia es: " + generoH + " libro/s");
    System.out.println("La cantidad de libros del genero novela es: " + generoN + " libro/s");
    System.out.println("El promedio de libros entre las estanterías es de: " + promedioLibros + " libro/s");
}
```

}

Comment: Hola! Bienvenido. Podrías aclarar que error te arroja?

Comment: Hola, como estas?! Gracias!

Ya se pudo resolver. El problema es que estaba usando dos metodos de ingresos por teclado. Input.next() para un char y Input.nextLine() para el string. El tema es q por algun motivo no se pueden usar los dos al mismo tiempo, por mas q sean para variables diferentes.
Lo resolvi cambiando la variable genero a string en vez de char!

Comment: Hola @DanielNoguera puedes usar Input.next() y Input.nextLine() al mismo tiempo, solo hay que saber donde aplicarlos, agregue una respuesta, prueba el còdigo que agrego, saludos.

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys!! Voy a tratar de entender en mayor profundidad ambos next, ya que aun no se como funciona el buffer

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta esta en que estaba usando dos metodos para pedir datos. Use el metodo input.next().charAt(0); para pedir un char, y el metodo input.nextLine() para pedir un String.

No entiendo el motivo, pero al usar los dos metodos dentro del mismo while, me toma solo el del char y no me toma el del string.

Resolvi el inconveniente transformando el char en string para utilizar un unico metodo de ingreso: input.nextLine();

El programa funciono correctamente.

Para el que quiera saber de que se trataba el programa, este es el ejercicio que lo genero:

La biblioteca de la ciudad necesita organizar y tener un recuento de los libros que
tiene en sus 5 estantes.
Por cada uno de los 5 estantes, se ingresan libros:
Por cada uno de esos libros ingresar:
▪ Nombre del libro (‘FIN’ = No hay más libros para ese estante)
▪ Género (‘I’ → Infantil, ‘N’ → Novela, ‘H’ → Historia)
▪ Cantidad de páginas que tiene el libro (mayor a 0)
Una vez finalizado el ingreso de datos de 1 estante, se debe mostrar por pantalla el
nombre del libro que más páginas tiene, con su cantidad correspondiente.
Al finalizar el ingreso de datos de todos los estantes, mostrar:
• Cantidad de libros por género
• Promedio de libros por estante

Comment: `next()` lee solo el siguiente *token*, pero se deja el salto de línea en el búfer, por lo que al hacer `nextLine()`, lee el salto de línea que te habías dejado al hacer `next()` y continúa directamente porque en realidad, sí que había una nueva línea en el búfer, por eso no te da tiempo a escribir nada más. La solución más sencilla es, cuando uses `next()`, haz a continuación un `nextLine()` (sin guardar el valor) para *limpiar* el búfer.

Comment: Gracias benito! Aun no tengo idea como funciona el tema del buffer y coko funciona la clase scanner. Recien estoy aprendiendo a resolver algoritmos usando java. Donde puedo encontrar informacion basica acerca del buffer?

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas usando `nextLine()`, deberìas usar `next()`, la diferencia es:

> `nextLine()` Avanza este escáner más allá de la línea actual y
> devuelve la entrada que se saltó.

> `next()` Encuentra y devuelve el siguiente token completo de este
> escáner.

por cierto, puedes agregar un `break;` para que pueda terminar correctamente el blucle al teclear "FIN", este serìa el còdigo usando  `next()` :

```
    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int cantLibros = 0, cantHojas, maxHojas, generoI = 0, generoN = 0, generoH = 0, promedioLibros;

    final int ESTANTERIAS = 5;

    char genero;

    String maxLibro, libro;

    for (int i = 1; i <= ESTANTERIAS; i++) {

        maxHojas = 0;
        maxLibro = "";

        System.out.println("Libros en estanteria nro: " + i);

        System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del libro (escriba FIN para finalizar la carga): ");

        //libro = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        libro = input.next().toUpperCase();

        while (!libro.equals("FIN")) {

            cantLibros++;

            do {
                System.out.println("Indique cuantas hojas tiene el libro: ");
                //cantHojas = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                cantHojas = Integer.parseInt(input.next());

            } while (cantHojas < 1);

            if (cantHojas > maxHojas) {

                maxHojas = cantHojas;
                maxLibro = libro;
            }

            do {
                System.out.println("Ingrese genero ('I': Infantil, 'N': Novela, 'H': Historia): ");
                genero = input.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);

            } while (genero != 'I' && genero != 'N' && genero != 'H');

            switch (genero) {

            case 'I':
                generoI++;
                break;

            case 'H':
                generoH++;
                break;

            case 'N':
                generoN++;
                break;
            }


            System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del libro (escriba FIN para finalizar la carga): ");

            //libro = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();
            libro = input.next().toUpperCase();

        }

        System.out.println(
                "El libro con mayor cantidad de hojas es: " + maxLibro + " y contiene: " + maxHojas + " hoja/s");
    //Termina bucle.
    break;
    }

    promedioLibros = cantLibros / ESTANTERIAS;

    System.out.println("La cantidad de libros del genero infantil es: " + generoI + " libro/s");
    System.out.println("La cantidad de libros del genero historia es: " + generoH + " libro/s");
    System.out.println("La cantidad de libros del genero novela es: " + generoN + " libro/s");
    System.out.println("El promedio de libros entre las estanterías es de: " + promedioLibros + " libro/s");


    }

}
```